# Concat multiple dataframes in Python reorders the columns by alphabet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have **NOT** a problem but a behaviour I would like to understand.

I have an Excel with 12 sheets, I want them all combined in 1 dataframe, with the sheetname as extra column. I can do it but have 1 strange behaviour I can't explain : the final order of columns of the dataframe is changed into and alphabetical order.

This is my flow :
I read through 10 sheets of an excel.
Every sheet is read in a dataframe,
all sheets have the same shape (73 rows x 50 columns) and the same hierarchical column. (2 levels).
When a sheet is read in, I append it to a dataframe, then I read the next sheet etc..

The result is a dataframe of 876rows and 50 columns. That is good.
But - as mentioned - with a different column order than the original set.

WORKAROUND : I save the order in a list and reapply it at the final dataframe, but that doesn't explain the behaviour.

If I try to replay this with a sample code (see underneath) but I cannot replay the behaviour, my sample code works as expected and preserves the order.
Any idea how I can start to investigate this behaviour?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

t0=pd.DataFrame()
t1=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape((4,3)), 
                columns=[['one','two','four'],['five','six','eight']])
t1['Month']='January'
t1.set_index(['Month'], inplace=True)

t2=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12,24).reshape((4,3)),
                columns=[['one','two','four'],['five','six','eight']])
t2['Month']='February'
t2.set_index(['Month'], inplace=True)

t3=pd.concat([t0,t1])
t3=pd.concat([t3,t2])
t3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an old version of Pandas?

Older defaulted `.concat()`'s `sort` arg to unset (`None`), which sorted based upon whether the data was already sorted, while the latest defaults to `False`

Try explicitly setting `sort=False` and/or upgrading Pandas if possible!

---

- [Pandas 0.23.4 docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html)

  > **sort** : boolean, default None
  >
  > Sort non-concatenation axis if it is not already aligned when *join* is ‘outer’.
  > The current default of sorting is deprecated and will change to not-sorting in a future version of pandas.
  >
  > Explicitly pass `sort=True` to silence the warning and sort. Explicitly pass `sort=False` to silence the warning and not sort.
  >
  > This has no effect when `join='inner'`, which already preserves the order of the non-concatenation axis.
  >
  > New in version 0.23.0.
- Pandas [latest stable](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [v1.2.1 (time of writing)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.1/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

  > **sort : bool, default False**
  >
  > Sort non-concatenation axis if it is not already aligned when join is ‘outer’. This has no effect when join='inner', which already preserves the order of the non-concatenation axis.
  >
  > Changed in version 1.0.0: Changed to not sort by default.